# hello, I am trying to load mp3 songs on my device in a recycler view and I am receiveing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android

please explain me what is going wrong. I can't seem to understand it. This is the complete error stack and below this I am adding `build.gradle` file. Please explain as to what is causing the error. Thank you.

```
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface;
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
            at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
            at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:215)
            at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:218)
            at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:336)
            at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:155)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
            at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:225)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:90)
            at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
            at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:245)
            at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:156)
            at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
            at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
            at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
            at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
            at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

Build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  
android {  
    compileSdkVersion 26  
    defaultConfig {  
        applicationId "com.example.dell.musicplayer"  
        minSdkVersion 21  
        targetSdkVersion 26  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"  
        testInstrumentationRunner  
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  
    }  
    buildTypes {  
        release {  
            minifyEnabled false  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'  
        }  
    }  
}  
dependencies {  
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'  
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'  
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.1'  
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'  
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'  
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'  
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'  
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'    
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'  
}
```

Also in my layout I am getting the following warning:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this
>   is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then
>   manually refresh the layout.

Comment: I don't think that this error relates to what you are trying to do. This is an IDE error sa far as I see.

Comment: Please post your app build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

The following problem:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface;
```

could probably because Glide is strictly using feature that didn't exist in support library 26.1.0. Glide is using support [library 27.1.0](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/gradle.properties). This is seem related with [ResourceCompat.getFont()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getFont(android.content.Context,%20int)) which is exist start from support library 27.1.0.

Try updating your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to **27**. And change all support library to **27.1.0**.

Comment: I tried using picasso instead of gilde still I got the same error

Comment: No I am just trying to read all MP3 files and display them on a recyclerview .